# It is possible to make just some tabs focusable (JTabbedPane)?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, focusable

It is possible to make just some tabs focusable, for instance the first 3 of 5 tabs? So that when changing tabs with the left - right keys, the non-focusable ones to be skipped (to be displayed only by mouse clicks).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Swing components use Actions to handle key events. So you can replace the existing action with a custom Action of your own.

Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) to see the Actions that are defined for a tabbed pane.

You may also find [Wrapping Actions](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/wrapping-actions/) and [Table Tabbing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/) helpful as they show how you can reuse existing Actions when customizing behaviour.